# C# converter : to use IValue converter or not

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ivalueconverter

I have a text box for temperature. And there is a combo box next to it that allows the user to choose which system he wants i.e Celsius or Fahrenheit .

Based on the selection in the combobox , the value should be changed in the text box automatically.

should I use a custom converter here i.e derived from IValueConverter ? if so how can i trigger it ?

the other option is I can latch onto combobox selection changed event . and in that i can get the value and convert it in a method based on whats selected in the drop down. this seems simpler to me with less code .

what are the pros and cons for each approach ?

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Temperature, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  />
<ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding TemperatureUnit}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource TempUnits}"   />
```

Comment: You can just change your view-model so that when `TemperatureUnit` is changed, the `Temperature` should be re-calculated and notified as changed (to update the text). Once you have an appropriate view-model, you don't need any converter (the logic is in code behind and the input can also be accessible right in code behind).

Comment: wow..how come this skipped me totally..

Comment: u shud answer this. so i can upvote, though it now looks like an incredibly silly question

Comment: btw you use Converter when there should be some value to be converted and that value is not present in your view-model. In this case you have `Temperature` present in your view-model, so you don't need Converter (in fact you convert/calculate in some helper method in code behind).